# Is it possible to simulate video playback in headless browser?

Tags: c#, puppeteer, vast

i have a video (vast) that when it runs it sends some http requests, i want to run a test on this in a headless browser (puppeteer, c#), is there a way to make the headless browser send these requests?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried whether it works?

Comment: @Riwen, I tried, it doesn't.

Comment: Please share your attempt as a [mcve]. Thanks.